# Как задержать отправку ответа с сервера Mysql

Tags: php

Есть javascript функция(AJAX), отправляющая данные и запрос на сервер каждую секунду, в ответ последовательно выводятся данные из таблицы. Как задержать отправку ответа с сервера, например установить какой-нибудь таймаут, чтобы ответ не отправлялся, пока скрипт не дождется хотя бы одной новой записи в таблице.
Вообщем нужно задержать ответ с сервера на 25 секунд к примеру...
Пробовал функцию sleep(), но есть ли еще что-нибудь подходящее?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, копать надо в сторону [Comet](http://abrdev.com/?p=1100).
Если лень или нет возможности разбираться, советую поставить задержку между запросами секунд 20 и возвращать только новые данные.

Answer (score 0):

А чем не устроил sleep? Можно сделать выборку количества count записей из таблицы, и делать проверку заданный интервал времени, если count изменилось/увеличилось, отправлять данные. Для этого можно использовать тот-же sleep